# Need Help Sorting a Table in Database for Most Viewed

Tags: count, group-by, sql-order-by, distinct

I am trying to figure out how to list which posts has been viewed the most, specifically the top 5.

```
viewid | postid | ip      | dateline

  1    |  16    | 1.1.1.1 | 987654
  2    |  12    | 1.1.1.1 | 987655
  3    |  15    | 2.2.2.2 | 987656
  4    |  16    | 2.2.2.2 | 987657
  5    |  16    | 3.3.3.3 | 987658
  6    |  18    | 1.1.1.1 | 987659
  7    |  16    | 1.1.1.1 | 987660
  8    |  12    | 4.4.4.4 | 987661
```

I would like to print out the following:

```
Post ID - 16 (3 views)
Post ID - 12 (2 views)
Post ID - 15 (1 view)
Post ID - 18 (1 view)
```

So even though there are 4 rows with post ID 16, it ignores 1 because that IP address has already seen it. Then it's sorted by most views and then sorted by timestamp.

This is what I currently am trying (not working):

```
$query_ranks_views = mysql_query("SELECT postid, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS num FROM views WHERE postid > '0' GROUP BY postid ORDER BY COUNT('DISTINCT ip') DESC LIMIT 5");
while($ranks_views = mysql_fetch_array($query_ranks_views)){
    echo("
        $ranks_views[postid] (". $ranks_views['COUNT(DISTINCT ip)'] .")
    ");
}
```

Comment: SQL part seems ok. What is the problem? What do you get as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query does work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95ee5/1
What is not correct is that you want to order by timestamp. Which timestamp? The timestamp of the post or the last timestamp of the view? Or maybe the average timestamp of view?

Comment: You have aliased the column as "num", try  $ranks_views['num'] .